# Encoding this logic sentence in Prolog: G ↔ ~Provable(x)

Tags: prolog

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%5C%2B/1
How would the above expression be encoded in Prolog?

Here it is in English for all the people that know Prolog
by do not know predicate logic:
G has the same truth value as its own unprovability.

Would every translation of the above logic expression always fail an occurs check?
http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=unify_with_occurs_check/2

Comment: @User9213 I just need a way to encode an expression of Prolog that directly tests its own most basic inference model: Prolog queries return "Yes" when-so-ever an expression is provable on the basis of the Facts and Rules in its database and returns "No" otherwise.

Comment: @User9213 Hopefully it is much more clearly a programming question now.   http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%5C%2B/1

Comment: @User9213 So If I ask you how do you write a prolog predicate that evaluates if two prolog expressions have the same truth value (logical equivalence) you would not be able to understand the question?

Comment: @User9213  Actually its the third equation of the Tarski Undefinability Theorem. This is ongoing research. -----(3) x ∉ Pr if and only if x ∈ Tr  -----
http://liarparadox.org/Tarski_Proof_275_276.pdf
So do you know how to help me or not?

Comment: @User9213 So you are saying that you don't know how to do it?

Comment: @User9213 No I did not notice that. Do you know much about the occurs check?

Comment: Friend, you really need to understand that Stackoverflow doesn't work like this. Read the intro or something.

Comment: @User9213 There is nothing in the intro that indicates my question is not appropriate.

Comment: @User9213 it is not about homework. It is about this research paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332158426_Tarski_Undefinability_Theorem_Succinctly_Refuted

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comments and now it looks like you are talking to yourself. I don't think they were relevant to your question.